# Enable ShowInTaskbar then SetParent() it disappears

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I am making a desktop widget application similar to Rainmeter for Windows 7/8.1/10 using C# WPF & .net 4.5.2. It finds the desktop window handle and sets my app as a child of it so I can create widgets. I am calling the following method from my MainWindow_Loaded method:

```
public static void SetOnDesktop(Window window)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        IntPtr hDesktop = FindWindow("ProgMan", "Program Manager");
        SetParent(hWnd, hDesktop);
    }
```

This function was working the other day. However, now it doesn't and I cannot figure out why. I tried running it under 7 and 10.

If I enable ShowInTaskbar in the main window, soon as I call SetParent(), it disappears from the taskbar; yet the process remained running.

Any ideas to why this is not working?

UPDATE :: I got this working with the following:

```
IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
IntPtr hDesktop = FindWindow("ProgMan", "SysListView32");
SetParent(hWnd, hDesktop);
```

However, I still would like to know what was going on.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: This is not how desktop widgets should be made. IIRC desktop widgets typically just normal windows that do their own custom nonclient area and don't have a taskbar button. (I've never seen the source for one so this is just an educated guess based on how Windows works.)

Comment: @andlabs - I've thought about using that method . However, I needed my widgets to be only on the desktop, below everything, and be dragable.

Comment: Microsoft refuses to document how to do this correctly.  Not that obvious why it is a secret, other than that it suffers heavily from the "what if *two* programs do this?" problem.  I suspect you like what you got from doing this intentionally wrong.  A desktop should *not* have a taskbar button, the built-in "show desktop" command is sufficient.  There is precedent for using a child window as a parent btw, Adobe did this with their browser plugin.  They could never get the awful focus problems sorted out.  If the big boys can't get this right, well, good luck :)

Comment: @HansPassant :: Thanks for the information. Yes, it appears to be working as I wanted. It seems to have an odd initial behavior though. Before when "Program Manager" worked, it would push the widget underneath Visual Studio at start. Now, it's on top initially, but, once focus is lost (ie: bringing VS back to the foreground), it's underneath for good. Bizarre.

Also, I enabled the taskbar icon as a sort of diagnostic visual when I could not locate my app's window. What's strange is that it sometimes is listed in the TaskView, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: In response to what you said about what I said, there are answers even on this site that explain how to create a window that resists focus and bring-to-frontness while still being draggable.

Comment: @andlabs - alright thanks, I will search for that specific issue.